# Version in "neo4j-uat.yaml" is unsupported. you're using the wrong Compose file version

Tags: docker, docker-compose, neo4j

I am trying to run the following docker-compose file but it always ends up with an error:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  neo4j:
    image: neo4j:5.8
    container_name: cybersage-neo4j
    hostname: neo4j
    user: 501:20 
    ports:
      - '0.0.0.0:9001:7474'
      - '0.0.0.0:9002:7687'
    volumes:
      - ./neo4j-config:/config
      - ./neo4j-data:/data:rw
      - ./neo4j-plugins:/plugins:rw
    environment:
      - NEO4J_server_memory_pagecache_size=1G
      - NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/admin12345678
      - NEO4J_apoc_export_file_enabled=true
      - NEO4J_apoc_import_file_enabled=true
      - NEO4J_apoc_import_file_use__neo4j__config=true
      - NEO4JLABS_PLUGINS=\[\"apoc\"\] \
      - NEO4J_dbms_security_procedures_unrestricted=apoc.\\\*
```

My docker-compose version is: **docker-compose version 1.25.0, build 0a186604**. Here is how I am trying to run it:

sudo docker-compose -f neo4j-uat.yaml up -d

```
ERROR: Version in "./neo4j-uat.yaml" is unsupported. You might be seeing this error because you're using the wrong Compose file version. 
Either specify a supported version (e.g "2.2" or "3.3") and place your service definitions under the `services` key, or omit the `version` key 
and place your service definitions at the root of the file to use version 1.
For more on the Compose file format versions, see https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/
```

This error appears if I remove the version from my docker-compose file:

```
ERROR: The Compose file './neo4j-uat.yaml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for services: 'neo4j'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all that the current Docker documentation shows examples with `version: '3.9'`, that was never actually a [Compose file format version](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/).  The most recent numbered versions are `2.4` (with extended plain-Docker options) and `3.8` (with extended Swarm-oriented options) and I'd use one of these.

Docker states that they no longer support the Python-based Compose 1.x as of June 2023.  The Go-plugin-based Compose 2.x completely ignores the `version:` field, which is why the documentation examples that show `version: '3.9'` apparently work.  (I've also seen some SO questions declaring `version: '1.2'` but Compose file format version 1 didn't support a `version:` field.)  Upgrading to the newer Compose will also make the file you show work.

Comment: I updated the docker-compose version on ubuntu and it is latest. if I remove the version, it still shows the error. I just added the error to question

Comment: I changed version to 3 and removed user property and it now works. Thanks